# ANGULARJS ng-repeat - iterating with objects['propertyname']

Tags: javascript, angularjs

how do you ng-repeat object with property names such as

```
$scope.myobjects = [
{
    'property1': {
        id: 0,
        name: 'somebody'
    }
}, 
{
    'property2': {
        id: 1,
        name: 'someguy'
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

As the keys of the object is not same, you can't just iterate it. May be you can do it in this way:

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/naketa/1/edit?html,js,output)**

```
<div ng-repeat="object in myobjects">{{getValue(object,'id') }}
  {{getValue(object,'name')}}
</div>
```

In your controller:

```
 $scope.getValue = function(value,field) {
    var key = Object.keys(value).filter(function(val) 
    {
      return val != "$$hashKey"
    })[0];
   return value[key][field];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a nested ng-repeat too like below if you want to take property names of objects (second one is looping into the objects):

```
<div ng-repeat="(index, object) in myobjects">
  <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in object">
    <strong>key: </strong> {{ key }}, <strong>value: </strong>{{ value }}
    <strong>value.id: </strong> {{ value.id }}, <strong>value.name: </strong>{{ value.name }}
  </div>
</div>
```

This prints:

**key:** property1, **value:** {"id":0,"name":"somebody"} **value.id:** 0, **value.name:** somebody

**key:** property2, **value:** {"id":1,"name":"someguy"} **value.id:** 1, **value.name:** someguy

Demo: http://embed.plnkr.co/SIMjaXMZPzbHLOCYRU8T/preview

Answer (score 0):

ng-repeat with obj prop

```
<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="abc">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in myobjects">
        <div ng-repeat="objProp in value">{{objProp.name}}</div>
    </div>
</div>

var app = angular.module('demo', []);
app.controller('abc', function ($scope) {
    $scope.myobjects = [{
        'property1': {
            id: 0,
            name: 'somebody'
        }
    }, {
        'property2': {
            id: 1,
            name: 'someguy'
        }
    }];
})
```

here is **working** [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BijayRai/1x0fuq05/)